# SASS --watch results in Errno::EOPNOTSUPP: Operation not supported

Tags: css, sass, listen

**I am getting an error when running sass --watch. It was not happening before.**

/mypath/ is a locally mounted ftp-directory.

I recently ran these commands:

- sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
- sudo gem install --version '~>
  0.8.8' rb-inotify

Errors:

```
masangapu@EBS-2012:/mypath/sass$ sass --watch localStorage.scss
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Errno::EOPNOTSUPP: Operation not supported - /mypath/sass/.listen_test
Use --trace for backtrace.



masangapu@EBS-2012:/mypath/sass$ sass --trace --watch localStorage.scss
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1140:in `initialize': Operation not supported - /mypath/sass/.listen_test (Errno::EOPNOTSUPP)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1140:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1140:in `rescue in block in touch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1136:in `block in touch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1134:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1134:in `touch'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:173:in `works?'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:152:in `block in     usable_and_works?'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:152:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:152:in `all?'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:152:in     `usable_and_works?'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/adapter.rb:46:in     `select_and_initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/multi_listener.rb:118:in     `initialize_adapter'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.6.0/lib/listen/multi_listener.rb:42:in     `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:307:in `watch'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin.rb:107:in `method_missing'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:444:in `watch_or_update'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:307:in `process_result'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/bin/sass:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

/mypath/ is a locally-mounted ftp-directory. Apparently sass does not work well with that.

I was able to run **sass --trace --watch --poll localStorage.scss**